# constructing a message format from the fetchall result in python

Tags: python, sql

****New to Programming***

Question: I need to use the below "Data" (two rows as arrays) queried from sql and use it to create the message structure below.

### data from sql using fetchall()

```
Data = [[100,1,4,5],[101,1,4,6]]
```

##expected message structure

```
message = {
            "name":"Tom",
            "Job":"IT",
            "info": [
               {
                "id_1":"100",
                "id_2":"1",
                "id_3":"4",
                "id_4":"5"
                },
               {
                "id_1":"101",
                "id_2":"1",
                "id_3":"4",
                "id_4":"6"
                },  
             ]
}
```

I tried to create below method to iterate over the rows and then input the values, this is was just a starting, but this was also not working

```
def create_message(data)
    for row in data:
       {
        "id_1":str(data[0][0],
        "id_2":str(data[0][1],
        "id_3":str(data[0][2],
        "id_4":str(data[0][3],
       }
```

Latest Code

```py
def create_info(data):
    info = []
    for row in data:
        temp_dict = {"id_1_tom":"","id_2_hell":"","id_3_trip":"","id_4_clap":""}
        for i in range(0,1):
            temp_dict["id_1_tom"] = str(row[i])
            temp_dict["id_2_hell"] = str(row[i+1])
            temp_dict["id_3_trip"] = str(row[i+2])
            temp_dict["id_4_clap"] = str(row[i+3])
        info.append(temp_dict)
    return info
```

Comment: Need to know how to create a structure and then insert data via loop while reading the values from db

Comment: Could you please describe what's your expected result from your entry data?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure how to create the message structure, I was just trying to create a method to loop through the rows and get value with indexes. But I don't know how to return the value from for loop to get the iterated details and then use that method to create the actual method. My method is not returning anything and I am not sure how to get required output

Comment: Basically you have data from db, you need to use python methods to create the "message" structure, values for name and job, I will get in params. I am concerned about how to use db output to construct message

Comment: No problem to me, but I'm just not sure to really understand what you are looking for (input/ output), thus a very concrete example is usually very helpful!

Comment: I thought I gave all the required information. input = Data (two rows from database), output required is "message". Need to use python to use input to create a message structure, where we insert the ids as per the rows fetched from db. let me know if its still unclear?

Comment: I actually do not see the link between `Data`, `message` and `create_message`. And and I have no clue of what output message you expect. I see a list of variables / dict keys, but nothing that looks like a final message (sorry if it's too late for me here in Europe ^^)

Comment: yeah, I think its late for you, so you are not able to make it up. message is the final output I need. create_message is just a method that I tried to create, you can ignore it. I need to create message from Data. thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Updated answer based on updates to the question and comment by original poster.

This function might work for the example you've given to get the desired output, based on the attempt you've provided:

```
def create_info(data):
    info = []
    for row in data:
        temp_dict = {}
        temp_dict['id_1_tom'] = str(row[0])
        temp_dict['id_2_hell'] = str(row[1])
        temp_dict['id_3_trip'] = str(row[2])
        temp_dict['id_4_clap'] = str(row[3])
        info.append(temp_dict)
    return info
```

For the input:

```
[[100, 1, 4, 5],[101,1,4,6]]
```

This function will return a list of dictionaries:

```
[{"id_1_tom":"100","id_2_hell":"1","id_3_trip":"4","id_4_clap":"5"}, 
{"id_1_tom":"101","id_2_hell":"1","id_3_trip":"4","id_4_clap":"6"}]
```

This can serve as the value for the key `info` in your dictionary `message`. Note that you would still have to construct the `message` dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I gave the random keys (id_1) for this post, those are actually different and without any pattern, how to handle those separate keys ? like id_1_trick, id_2_hell etc.

Comment: I restructured the code a bit as per my requirement. Need to know if that is the correct way. I am not able to format it on the page to look pretty. Once this part is done, I will work on the whole message part

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comments and the edit to your question.